# Accept or decline Friend Request using FB Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

How I can accept or decline friend requests of other users via Graph API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read friend requests by looking at the [friend_request table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend_request/) with FQL and the "read_requests" extended permission.  The public API does not support managing those (accepting/denying).  There may be a way if you get whitelisted somehow and get access to undocumented API's, but this is pure speculation.